# Swift Binary string to Int

Tags: swift

Having some issues converting a binary string to a Int.

The int value:

-294155939

The int value as binary:

11101110011101111000100101011101

The way im currently converting the binary to an int is like this

```
Int("11101110011101111000100101011101", radix:2) -> 4000811357

Int32("11101110011101111000100101011101", radix:2) -> nil

Int64("11101110011101111000100101011101", radix:2) -> 4000811357
```

I also tried UInt, obviously this didn't give the correct output as as UInt is unsigned and cant go below 0.

```
UInt("11101110011101111000100101011101", radix:2) -> 4000811357
```

Im unsure why my int representation of the binary string is coming out how it is. Is there another way to convert the binary to a signed int?

Comment: I have tried this already, it gives nil as the result

Comment: `Int(Int32(bitPattern: UInt32("11101110011101111000100101011101", radix:2)!))`